# Is there a way to speed-up openMP

Tags: c, for-loop, time, openmp

I am solving a problem that compares execution times between a serial, an mpi and an openMP code. The problem is that the openMP version is slower than mpi. Is there a way to evolve the openMP code below to be faster than mpi?

```
for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
  {
    #pragma omp parallel for private(k,dx,dy,dz,d,a) schedule(dynamic)
      for(j=0;j<N;j++)
      {
        for(k=0;k<N;k++)
        {
          if(j!=k)
          {
            dx=C[k*3+0]-C[j*3+0];
            dy=C[k*3+1]-C[j*3+1];
            dz=C[k*3+2]-C[j*3+2];

            d=sqrt(pow(dx,2)+pow(dy,2)+pow(dz,2));

            F[j*3+0]-=G*M[j]*M[k]/pow(d,3)*dx;
            F[j*3+1]-=G*M[j]*M[k]/pow(d,3)*dy;
            F[j*3+2]-=G*M[j]*M[k]/pow(d,3)*dz;
          }
        }
      }
      #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
          for(k=0;k<3;k++)
          {
            a=F[j*3+k]/M[j];
            V[j*3+k]=V[j*3+k]+a*Dt[i];
            C[j*3+k]=C[j*3+k]+V[j*3+k]*Dt[i];
          }
        }
  }
```

What this code do is that the outer loop is the times the process is going to take place and is also used in the `Dt` table in the end. The second loop describes a mass that moves and the third calculates the forces that been pushing it from the other masses existing  in the system. The two loop after that calculates the new position. With this in mind I can't move the parallelism in the outer loop because in every `i` circle a new updated `C` table needed. So is there anything to be changed so this code can run faster.

For more info about the problem

- `loop`: takes value between 10.000 - 1,000,000,000 (provided from user)
- `N`: takes values between 2 - 10 (provided from user)
- `C`: takes random values between `min` and `max` (provided from user)
- `F` and `V`: initial values 0.00
- `G`: 6.673e-11

Allocation of the tables

```
M=malloc(N*sizeof(int));

C=malloc(N*3*sizeof(float));

F=malloc(N*3*sizeof(float));
V=malloc(N*3*sizeof(float));

Dt=malloc(loop*sizeof(float));
```

Table values

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  M[i]=rand()%(high-low+1)+low;
}

for(i=0;i<N*3;i++)
{
  C[i]=rand()%(max-min+1)+min;

  F[i]=0.0;
  V[i]=0.0;
}

for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
{
  Dt[i]=(float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
}
```

Comment: How large is `N`? If it's fairly large, you may be having cache miss performance problems. Can you a bit more of the code? Particularly, the definitions of the various arrays (e.g. `C`). And, some initial values. In other words, enough to download/compile/run. And, your code relies [heavily] on the optimizer to do common subexpression elimination (e.g. Do you really want to calculate `pow(d,3)` three times for each loop iteration?)

Comment: N takes values between 2-10. Yes parts like `pow(d,3)` can and must be replaced but the problem dosen't lies there because the same time it costs to the openMP code the same it costs me in the mpi code too. I am going to post info about the tables and their values in the main code above.

Comment: As I said, please post more of your code. How big is `loop`? I just refactored your code and got a 4.4x speedup without using omp at all. I used an `N` value of 64 and `loop` of 100 and this runs in 3-16ms. So, what are the real numbers?

Comment: My latest version is now 11x faster and runs in 1ms.

Comment: The  point of  this is that I have to compare the speed up between a serial, mpi and openMP version of the same code. I posted some extra information I hope to be helpfull.

Comment: As a general performance tip, not related to parallelism, unless you need the specific semantics that `pow()` provides for various special cases involving infinities, signed zeroes, and overflows, you are usually better off computing small integer powers by multiplication.   That is `dx * dx` is usually better than `pow(dx, 2)`, and `d * d * d` is usually better than `pow(d, 3)`.

Comment: You should've said in the beginning that `loop` takes such huge values and `N` such small values. The fork/join model of OpenMP has certain overhead for each activation of a parallel region and having it nested in a loop multiplies the overhead. This is really the worst use case for OpenMP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may start by replacing `schedule(dynamic)` with `schedule(static)`. There is absolutely no need for dynamic scheduling here since the amount of work done by each iteration is constant. `schedule(dynamic)` defaults to chunk size of `1` and dynamically assigns **each** iteration to some thread with the associated huge overhead.

Dynamic scheduling is useful when each iteration involves a varying amount of work, in which case static scheduling **may** lead to load imbalance and idling threads. A canonical case is colouring a fractal set. Even then, it is often more reasonable to dispatch work items in chunks of more than one iteration in order to minimise the dispatch overhead.

The second loop is not running in parallel since what you have there is an orphaned OpenMP `for` construct instead of a combined `parallel for` one. You also need to make `k` and `a` private.

---

Now that we know that `N` is really small and `loop` takes such large values, there are some things that can be done to improve the performance.

First, there is no such thing as "calling `omp parallel` once to start the parallelism". There are parallel regions that execute in parallel whenever the flow control passes through them. A parallel region is a block of code following the OpenMP `parallel` construct. OpenMP worksharing constructs such as `for` only execute in parallel when inside the dynamic scope of a parallel region. The second loop is therefore not parallel since it is only a `for` construct and is not nested lexically or dynamically in a `parallel` region.

To make the terminology clear, lexical nesting of an OpenMP construct inside a parallel region means:

```c
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp for
   for (...) {}
}
```

and dynamic nesting means:

```c
foo() {
  #pragma omp for
  for (...) {}
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
  foo();
}
```

Just calling `foo()` from outside a parallel region will **not** make the loop run in parallel.

There are shorthand combined constructs such as `parallel for` for when the only code in the body of a parallel region is a worksharing construct such as `for`.

Second, parallel regions are not for free. OpenMP follows the fork/join model of parallel computation where the program executes sequentially until the flow of execution encounters a parallel region. When that happens, a *fork* of worker threads occurs and the program starts to execute in parallel. At the end of the parallel region, the worker threads are *joined* back into the main thread and the program continues to execute sequentially. Forking and joining have their price in terms of execution time. Although practically all modern OpenMP runtimes use thread pools and only the very first parallel region activation is really slow due to the time it takes the OS to spawn all the worker threads, the fork/join overhead is still not negligible. Therefore, it is meaningless to use OpenMP unless there is enough work to be distributed between the threads so that the overhead can be amortised.

Here is an illustration of the problem. Four iterations, each taking one time unit, computed sequentially and in parallel with two threads. The overhead for both fork and join is two time units:

```
|    sequential                 parallel
|  +------------+     +-------------------------+
|  |    it.0    |     |          fork           |
|  |    it.1    |     |        overhead         |
|  |    it.2    |     |    it.0    |    it.2    |
|  |    it.3    |     |    it.1    |    it.3    |
|  +------------+     |          join           |
|                     |        overhead         |
|                     +-------------------------+
v  time
```

Although dividing the iterations between two threads make the computation twice as fast, the overhead makes the parallel version slower overall.

The same, but now with ten iterations:

```
|    sequential                 parallel
|  +------------+     +-------------------------+
|  |    it.0    |     |          fork           |
|  |    it.1    |     |        overhead         |
|  |    it.2    |     |    it.0    |    it.5    |
|  |    it.3    |     |    it.1    |    it.6    |
|  |    it.4    |     |    it.2    |    it.7    |
|  |    it.5    |     |    it.3    |    it.8    |
|  |    it.6    |     |    it.4    |    it.9    |
|  |    it.7    |     |          join           |
|  |    it.8    |     |        overhead         |
|  |    it.9    |     +-------------------------+
|  +------------+
|
v  time
```

Clearly, the parallel version is now faster and will get even faster the more iterations there are, approaching asymptotically from below a speedup of 2x. Note that the problem here is not that there are only four iterations in the first case, but that those iterations take only one time unit each. It is fine to use OpenMP for a problem with small number of iterations but large amount of computational time per iteration.

The problem in the first case can be greatly exacerbated if the parallel region is inside an outer loop that with many iterations, which is exactly your case. The canonical solution is to move the outer loop inside the parallel region. This way, there will be a single fork and a single join and the overhead will not get replicated. With your code, something like this:

```c
#pragma omp parallel private(i,k,dx,dy,dz,d,a)
for(i=0;i<loop;i++)
{
   #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
   for(j=0;j<N;j++)
   {
      for(k=0;k<N;k++)
      {
         if(j!=k)
         {
            dx=C[k*3+0]-C[j*3+0];
            dy=C[k*3+1]-C[j*3+1];
            dz=C[k*3+2]-C[j*3+2];

            d=sqrt(pow(dx,2)+pow(dy,2)+pow(dz,2));

            F[j*3+0]-=G*M[j]*M[k]/pow(d,3)*dx;
            F[j*3+1]-=G*M[j]*M[k]/pow(d,3)*dy;
            F[j*3+2]-=G*M[j]*M[k]/pow(d,3)*dz;
         }
      }
   }

   #pragma omp for schedule(static)
   for(j=0;j<N;j++)
   {
      for(k=0;k<3;k++)
      {
         a=F[j*3+k]/M[j];
         V[j*3+k]=V[j*3+k]+a*Dt[i];
         C[j*3+k]=C[j*3+k]+V[j*3+k]*Dt[i];
      }
   }
}
```

You have to be very careful now because the entire loop is inside the parallel region and each thread is executing all iterations, i.e., there is no distribution of iterations. There is no worksharing directive applied to the `i`-loop and therefore `i` must be given explicitly the `private` treatment. A better coding style would have all private variables declared inside the parallel region, in which case there will be no need for a `private` clause at all, but this is not done here for demonstration reasons.

Because the `i`-loop iterations are not independent from one another, you have to make sure that all threads are doing them in lock-step. This is usually achieved with barrier synchronisation, which in the code above comes from the implicit barriers at the end of the `for` constructs. The same applies to different stages inside the iteration. Again, here the second worksharing construct does not start before the previous one has finished due to the implicit barrier at the end of the latter.

Comment: Yes there is no actual need of `schedule(dynamic)` so I change it to `schedule(static)`. From the other hand I knew that the `omp parallel` part need to be called only one in the code just to start the parallelism and the private declares in there apply to all the parallel regions. I made the correction in the second `omp for` (private(k,a) and parallel for) and the results were the same but the time the  process took was more than before.

Comment: You state that `N` is between 2 and 10. That means between 2 and 90 executions of the inner loop's body. There simply isn't enough work to amortise the OpenMP overhead. Note that you can cut the number of iterations of the inner loop in half by exploiting the symmetry (and that's when you'll need dynamic scheduling).

Comment: With the code provides I made the changes and now runs faster than mpi. Thanks a lot for the extend information where very helpfull

Comment: @SerrisFilippos If that answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Otherwise Stack Overflow will keep showing the question as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The very frist thing to do is to set up a time measurement and check if this snippent is your hotspot. (I think you already did this, since you compared openMP to mpi)

Here are my thoughts:

- Make all local variables local.
- Check if the dynamic scheduling really helps you
- Reduce superfluous calculations pow(sqrt(x),3) = pow(x,1.5)
- if `N` is not too large, I suggest that you once pre calculate `M_once[j+N*k]=M[j]*M[k]`. If `j==k` you can set M_once to zero and thus save time for the branching (if statement).

Here is the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<loop;i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
      for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
      {
        for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
        {
          if(j!=k)
          {
            const double dx=C[k*3+0]-C[j*3+0];
            const double dy=C[k*3+1]-C[j*3+1];
            const double dz=C[k*3+2]-C[j*3+2];

            const double d=pow(dx,2)+pow(dy,2)+pow(dz,2);

            const double factor = G*M[j]*M[k]/pow(d,1.5); 

            F[j*3+0] -= factor * dx;
            F[j*3+1] -= factor * dy;
            F[j*3+2] -= factor * dz;
          }
        }
      }
      #pragma omp for 
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
          for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
          {
            const double a = F[j*3+k] / M[j];
            V[j*3+k] = V[j*3+k] + a * Dt[i];
            C[j*3+k] += V[j*3+k] * Dt[i];
          }
        }
  }
```